# Plotting secondary Y-axis using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My current code takes a list from a csv file and lists the header for the user to pick from so it can plot.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('log40a.csv',index_col=False)

from collections import OrderedDict
headings = OrderedDict(enumerate(df,1))
for num, heading in headings.items():
    print("{}) {}".format(num, heading))

print ('Select X-Axis')
xaxis = int(input())

print ('Select Y-Axis')
yaxis = int(input())

df.plot(x= headings[xaxis], y= headings[yaxis])
```

My first question. How do I add a secondary Y axis. I know with matplotlib I first create a figure and then plot the first yaxis with the xaxis and then do the same thing to the 2nd yaxis. However, I am not sure how it is done in pandas. Is it similar?

I tried using matplotlib to do it but it gave me an error:

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize= (10,10))
ax = fig1.add_subplot(211)
ax.plot(headings[xaxis], headings[yaxis], label='Alt(m)', color = 'r')
ax.plot(headings[xaxis], headings[yaxis1], label='AS_Cmd', color = 'blue')
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized character a in format string
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array with the column names that you want plotted on the y axis.

An example if you delimite the y columns with a ','

```
df.plot(x= headings[xaxis], y=headings[yaxis.split(",")], figsize=(15, 10))
```

To run it you will need to change your input method, so that it is an array rather then a string.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the Index and columns part? I am not trying to specify the column number ahead of time because I need the user to give me the columns he wants to plot. If I did what you did the columns would be set.

Comment: You will need to either A) set the input to an array, and append future values, or B) allow the user to input multiple methods, and then split the string into an array of separated values. I have updated my answer for the split method, which is probably the easiest.

Comment: I see what you mean now. However, when I did try your solution. I got an error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. Note: I did change yaxis = input() so that I receive a string.